# Unable to switch to GNOME on Ubuntu Budgie 18.04

Tags: 18.04, gnome, desktop-environments, budgie

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 with Budgie preinstalled (default for Tuxedo computers), and I'm trying to use GNOME desktop environment.

I installed `ubuntu-desktop` meta-package using

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop
```

but even after restarting I can't see the gear icon to switch desktop.

After the first restart, I got some "GNOME welcoming message" (asking for keyboard setup and online accounts) and I suppose I have more gnome-applications than before, but that's all.

I have the GNOME 'settings' application, but I suppose it's also the default one for Budgie. In the 'about' section it mentions GNOME version : 3.28.2

I had to install GNOME on my last Tuxedo too, but I can't remember what I did differently.